# Store environment value in Vue upon app initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

In a basic web app built using VueJS a call is made to an API that responds with an object containing the environment name.  For example:
`https://appsdev/mysimpleapp/api/environment`
returns
`{"applicationName":"My Simple App","version":"1.0.0.0","environment":"DEV"}`

Currently, a nav button is set up to conditionally show if the environment is `DEV`.  Here are the pertinent parts of that page:

```
<template>
   <!-- other content here -->
   <div @click="updateMenu()" v-show="['DEV'].includes(environment)"><router-link :to="{name: 'dev-notes'}">Dev Notes</router-link></div>
</template>

<script>
// other logic here
data() {
    return {
        environment: null
    }
},
created() {
    this.getEnvironment();
},
methods: {
    async getEnvironment() {
        const environmentDetails = await this.$service.access('environment').get();  // uses Axios to access API
            this.environment = environmentDetails.environment;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

While this approach works, there is a noticeable delay in the "Dev Notes" nav button appearing while the app hits the API.  Plus, every time the page loads, there is a call to the API.

Looking to improve upon this, it seems like it might be better to hit the API once, when the app initializes, store that value in a variable somewhere and then refer to that variable for conditionally showing the "Dev Notes" nav button.  Vuex seems like overkill for such a simple thing and this app doesn't have the .env files that [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-working-with-environment-variables) describes so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the environment mode info straight from Vue CLI using node's `process.env`, which is a feature that's available by default.  Specifically, `process.env.NODE_ENV` tells whether the app is running in production or development or some other mode.  From the Vue CLI [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables):

> For example, NODE_ENV will be set to "production" in production mode, "test" in test mode, and defaults to "development" otherwise.

You can test this anywhere in your project, for example:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log('PRODUCTION');
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  console.log('DEVELOPMENT');
} else {
  console.log('OTHER');
}
```